# Prevent editor from converting tags width size with percent unit to pixel unit

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

when I used WYSIWYG, any percent unit would be converted to pixel unit.

Instead of this:
`<div style="width:244px;">...</div>`

I want this:
`<div style="width:50%;">...</div>`

My CKEditor version is 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

The CKEDITOR.config.width option sets the outer size of the entire editor interface, including the border. This configuration option accepts an integer (to denote a value in pixels) or any CSS-defined length unit, including percent (%).

For example:

```
config.width = 500;     // 500 pixels wide.
config.width = '75%';   // CSS unit (percent).
```

The CKEDITOR.config.height option sets the height of the editing area with CKEditor content — it does not include the toolbar or the bottom bar. This configuration option accepts an integer (to denote a value in pixels) or any CSS-defined length unit except percent (%) values which are not supported.

For example:

```
config.height = 500;        // 500 pixels high.
config.height = '25em';     // CSS unit (em).
```

You can refer the below url as well
[docs.ckeditor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_size)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but you misunderstood my subject. I wanna control the behaviors of editor instead of setting the outer size of the entire editor interface.